# Displaying column name, when x is found in a row

Tags: excel

I am looking to develop a function in excel that outputs column names, where x is found in a row. 
For example: 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgPpn.png)

That is, I am looking to scan through E2:E2 for "x", and display the corresponding column name(s) found in B2:E1 in an output cell such as F2, F3, and F4.

I have tried using IF, COUNTIF, and LOOKUP, but I cannot find a way to make the output cell display the names of the column for each instance that x is found. 
I have been playing with this expression: `=IF(COUNTIF(B2:E2,"x"),1,"")`, but instead of returning 1, I would want to return "A" in this case, as that is the column value associated with the x that was found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) if you have Excel 2016 or Office365, otherwise this will require VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In later versions of Excel, you can use the `TextJoin` function:

Suppose your data is in range `A:E` and you want your formula in column `F`.

If `F2`, enter the **array** formula:

```
F2:  =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE, IF(B2:E2="x",$B$1:$E$1,""))
```

And remember array formula, so, after typing it in, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please try, in F2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(B2="X",B$1,"")&IF(C2="X",C$1,"")&IF(D2="X",D$1,"")&IF(E2="X",E$1,"")
```